# What different Scripting and Programming languages is available on Mac OSX by default?

Tags: macos, scripting, programming-languages

This for the sake of knowledge and interrest. A colleague of mine started out with Python and wanted to know what she could use to install an interpreter on her Mac. I told her, she shouldn't worry about that, Mac OSX already has one by default. I also mention to her that php is also available on Mac. That sort of triggered me and I went and checked if Perl was also available on Mac OSX by default. And it was :O

Is there more programming languages and scripting languages that come along with Mac OSX by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby, and some shells (bash, tcsh, ksh, zsh).